# How should I model this data?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, count-data

I need to use R studio to model the following problem:

According to the Independent newspaper (London, March 8, 1994), the Metropolitan Police in London reported 30,475 people as missing in the year ending March 1993. For those of age 13 or less, 33 of 3271 missing males and 38 of 2486 missing females were still missing a year later. For ages 14–18, the values were 63 of 7256 males and 108 of 8877 females; for ages 19 and above, the values were 157 of 5065 males and 159 of 3520 females. Analyze these data, including checking model fit and interpreting parameter estimates.

I know that the prediction equation should look like this:

Y= -3.4369 +0.3803(x1) -1.1279(x2) -1.3259(x3)

Where x1, x2, and x3 correspond to the age groups.

But I'm having problems setting it up.

Here's what I tried:

```
A1=(33/3238)*100
B1=(63/7193)*100
C1=(157/4980)*100
D1=(38/2448)*100
E1=(108/8769)*100
F1=(159/3361)*100

missing=c(A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1)
sex=c("M","M","M", "F", "F", "F")
Age=c("less13", "14to18", "19more","less13", "14to18", "19more")

Missing=data.frame(missing, sex, Age)
Missing

TACO= glm(missing~ Age*sex, family=poisson, data=Missing)
g=summary(TACO)
g
```

But I get many errors and I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

Comment: You have destroyed half your data by converting everything to percents.  Please read the documentation for `glm` and focus on the binomial family--you have to chase through some links, but you will eventually find working code and examples.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I know that the prediction equation should look like this?*" Because that does not make sense, in a couple levels: i) where is sex? If it's not in it, why did you put sex in the model? ii) given that there are only three age groups, how come all three of them got into the regression? (If a categorical has k levels, it'd only be modeled with (k-1) binary "dummy" indicators." Regardless where you got this "model answer" from, I'd suggest extra caution.

Answer (score 0):

As already said in comments, you should analyze your counts as is, and not convert to percentages. The information in a percent value of 10% is very different between 1 of 10, or 100 of thousand, say ... and you loose that information! So you could analyze this as binomial data, with a logistic regression. I just give some code to get you started:

```
Y <- c(33, 38, 63, 108, 157, 159)
N <- c(3271, 2486, 7256, 8877, 5065, 3250)
Gender <- factor(rep(c("M", "F"), 3), levels=c("M", "F"))
Age <- c("<=13", "14-18", ">=19","<13", "14-18", ">=19")

missing <- data.frame(Y=Y,  N=N, Gender=Gender, Age=Age)

mod1 <- glm( cbind(Y, N-Y) ~ Age, family=binomial, data=missing)

summary(mod1)

Call:
glm(formula = cbind(Y, N - Y) ~ Age, family = binomial, data = missing)

Deviance Residuals: 
     1       2       3       4       5       6  
 0.000  -3.581  -8.350   0.000   2.251   9.429  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -4.5862     0.1750 -26.213  < 2e-16 ***
Age<13        0.1894     0.2000   0.947    0.344    
Age>=19       0.7505     0.1877   4.000 6.34e-05 ***
Age14-18      0.9559     0.1894   5.047 4.49e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 237.77  on 5  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 176.53  on 2  degrees of freedom
AIC: 221.53

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

This is just a start of a full analysis ... I leave it there. Just a hint: look at the large deviance residuals.